# Unable to start Codeblocks IDE

Tags: ide, codeblocks

On starting **Codeblocks**, codeblocks is minimizing to the taskbar and is not responding.

I have tried uninstalling it and installing it again by downloading.

How to start it?

Codeblocks 64bit 13.12 version

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to open the task manager ( if you are using Windows, you can press "ctrl + shift + esc" ) to kill some process related to codeblocks program ? Then you can relaunch the program to see if it will work.